# Hiding a Button in a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I currently have a table with 8 rows that each have a label on the right side and a button on the left. I was hoping that I could have all the buttons hidden until the user presses an "edit" button in the top right corner and then they would appear allowing the user to interact with each table cell. I don't know if this is possible, because they are in `UITableViewCell`s or if there is an easier method to summoning a button for each cell

**UPDATE**

okay so I have placed in all the hidden properties and there seem to be no errors, but the app doesn't recognize any of it. The buttons remains unhidden despite the fact that they are set to be initially hidden. Here is my code

Here is my Table Cell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BlockCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Free Block";

    UIButton*BlockButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    BlockButton.frame = CGRectMake(225.0f, 5.0f, 75.0f, 35.0f);
    [BlockButton setTitle:@"Change" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [BlockButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Switch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    Blockbutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:102/255.f
                                                 green:0/255.f
                                                 blue:51/255.f
                                                 alpha:255/255.f];
    Blockbutton.hidden = YES;
    [cell addSubview:BlockButton];
    return cell;
}
```

and here is my method code:

```
- (IBAction)Editmode:(UIButton *)sender 
{
    Blockbutton.hidden = !Blockbutton.hidden;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

any thoughts or ideas as to what might be the issue?

Comment: It is possible. The buttons have a `hidden` property you can set to YES or NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to keep in mind that a table's cells are determined by `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You can cause that method to be called all over again by sending the table `reloadData:`.

So, just keep a BOOL instance variable / property. Use the button to toggle that instance variable and to call `reloadData:`. If, at the time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, the instance variable is YES, set the button's `hidden` to YES; if NO, to NO.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I seem to be having an issue

Comment: sorry I accidentally hit enter and commented, anyways this may sound really stupid but where can I find the name or pointer of my UITableView in my UITableViewController, I don't exactly know what object is calling the <reloadData> method so I am getting a "no known class method for selector reloadData" error message on my line of code that just says <[UITableView reloadData];>

Comment: It is `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Comment: Did you know you could have found that out by looking at the UITableViewController documentation?

Comment: I was pretty sure about it being called "tableview" but I guess I just had a brain fart and forgot the self., but thank you for the reminder and I will be sure to reference that next time.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass if you don't already have one.  In that class, override `setEditing:animated:` and if the new value is `YES`, then enable/add/unhide the button.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        // add your button
        someButton.hidden = NO;

    } else {
        // remove your button
        someButton.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

It would be optional, but you are encouraged to animate the change if `animated` is `YES`.

*Note*: this assumes you have the edit button already hooked up the change the editing mode of the `UITableView`.  If you don't, call `setEditing:animated:` on the `UITableView` in the button action.  This will automatically call `setEditing:animated:` on each visible table cell.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked perfectly for me. I just wanted to add that that whole if statement could be replaced with just a single line of code: `someButton.hidden = !editing`

Answer (score 0):

take a BOOL variable which defines the whether to show delete button or not, use this BOOL var to for btnName.hidden = boolVar, initially make boolVar = NO, when user taps on edit toggle bool var and reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to test if you are in edit mode in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     UITableViewCell *cell = //(obtain your cell however you like)
     UIButton *button = cell.button; //(get button from cell using a property, a tag, etc.)
     BOOL isEditing = self.editing //(obtain the state however you like)
     button.hidden = !isEditing;
     return cell;
}
```

And whenever you enter editing mode, reload tableView data. This will make the table view ask for the cells again, but in this case the buttons will be set not to hide.

```
- (void)enterEditingMode {
    self.editing = YES;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```